# Same height in columns using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to get same height in columns using css. The gray one must have same height!

How can i do this?
i've tried with:

http://www.bootply.com/vMeGSIHxO7#

(the gray columns must have the same dynamic height)

Comment: is it ok if i will add custom css for one column or you need for all?

Comment: i need the same dynamic height for the 2 grey columns

Comment: the problem is nesting row and columns keeping the same height between the columns, in the sample: " zxc this is my test this is my test" must have the same height (dynamic) of "zxc this is my test this is my test this is my test this is my test"

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use media queries to set the height. Give them all a class and then set height for that class.

I understand that there is also now an col-eq-height class (or similar) in bootstrap, but I haven't used it.

EDIT - further explanation about using the media queries method 
(there is probably an easier way):

As browser width's change, the content heights will change. Once you have given each column the relevant height class, then starting at mobile expanding upward, use media queries to 'reset' heights as appropriate.

EG:

```
.height <!--example class, nothing set first as assuming columns will be stacking on top of each other at mobile -->
{
}

@media (min-width: 768px) <!--example change point 1 -->
{
    .height
        {
            height: Xpx;
        }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) <!--example change height 2 -->
{
    .height
        {
            height: Ypx;
        }
}
```

FURTHER EDIT:

Using two separate height classes:

EG HTML

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 height-outer">
                <div class="col-xs-6 height-inner">
                    zxc
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 height-inner">
                    this is my test
                    this is my test
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 height-outer">
                <div class="col-xs-6 height-inner">
                    zxc
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 height-inner">
                    this is my test 
                    this is my test
                     this is my test
                    this is my test 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

EG CSS

```
        .height-outer
        {
        background: black;
        height: 350px;
        }

        .height-inner
        {
        background: blue;
        height: 320px;
        }

        @media (min-width: 385px) 
        {   .height-outer {height: 190px}
            .height-inner {height: 170px;}
        }

        @media (min-width: 535px) 
        {   .height-outer {height: 100px}
            .height-inner {height: 80px;}
        }

        @media (min-width: 992px) 
        {   .height-outer {height: 70px}
            .height-inner {height: 50px;}
        }
```

Comment: hi tbb thanks for the answer, what if i desire dynamic height?

Comment: By dynamic height, do you mean changing the set height to suit the change in the columns' contents' height as the browser changes width? If so, I have edited more fully explaining.

Comment: Sorry - I used min height to begin with - for some reason. Shouldn't change outcome, but could cause confusion if height was set to less than largest/highest column contents. I have changed now.

Comment: this is a great solution but i need a dynamic height :(

so the 2 external container <div class="col-xs-6"> must have the same height of the other external container <div class="col-xs-6">

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use the same principle above, but with specific height classes for the outer and inner boxes? eg: `.height-outer` and `.height-inner`

Comment: this is another great solution but i need a responsive way:

in this sample http://www.bootply.com/pRh62oPJGv there is my problem.

image is responsive so i need a responsive columns :S

Comment: Ahhh! Now I understand better. You have pictures, not just texts. I think that this might help: http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, is to create something like a sidebar and and a main section..

Assuming that you have the following code

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar"> sidebar code goes here </div>
  <div id="main"> main section code goes here </div>
</div>
```

you can use something like the following css code

```
#wrapper{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red 25%, blue 25%); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, red 25%, blue 25%); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, red 25%, blue 25%); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(left, red 25%, blue 25%); /* Standard syntax */
}
#sidebar{ width: 25%; }
#main{ width: 75%; }
```

so your wrapper div take the max height of the two other divs and use its own background colour

Hope it helps

Comment: the problem is nesting row and columns keeping the same height between the columns, in the sample: 
"
zxc
this is my test this is my test"

must have the same height (dynamic) of 

"zxc
this is my test this is my test this is my test this is my test"